# List of KeyValuePair to be Distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, keyvaluepair

I have a list of KeyValuePair which its values are list too such as

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> ListX = new List<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>();
ListX.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("a",list1));
ListX.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("b",list1));
ListX.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>("a",list1));`
```

I want the keys of each KeyValuePair in the list to be not duplicated, only the keys, can I use Distinct in this list?

for example I want the third item in the list that has "a" key to be deleted because it's duplicated.

Comment: use `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` instead. Add method throws exception if key already exist. you can use `ContainsKey` method first to check if key already exist. or you can use indexer instead of Add method which overwrites the old value if key already exist. `dic["a"] = list1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it is possible to work around with your current `List` to make it having `Distinct` keys, the simplest solution which I think fit for your case is to use `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

It does *just exactly* what you need:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("a", new List<string>());
dict.Add("b", new List<string>());
dict.Add("a", new List<string>()); //will throw an error
```

Image:

[image]

If you need to check if a `Key` is already exist when you want to add a `<Key,Value>` to a your dictionary, simply check by `ContainsKey`:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) //the key exists
```

Comment: This works well, I didn't have an idea that dictionary can have more than 1 item.thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
var dictionaryX = ListX
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key, (x, ys) => ys.First())
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but it's a query that will convert a `ListX` into a dictionary by only taking the first value for each duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. It is a collection of KeyValuePairs which allows only unique keys.

Comment: It will give me an error if I'm trying to add duplicate key?right? I don't want an error to be appeared, I want it to prevent adding it without giving an error

Comment: @user1947393 Just add a check before inserting an item `if(!d.ContainsKey(key))`

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

where Tkey and Tvalue are generic datatypes.

For example they can be int, string,another dictionary etc.

Example`Dictionary<int , string>, Dictionary<int , List<employee>>` etc.

In all these cases the **key is the distinct part** ie, same key cannot be inserted again.

U can check if key exists using **Distinct** so that no exception occurs even if u try to add same key

However **Distinct prevents only same key value pairs** .

To **prevent same key being** added use `Enumerable.GroupBy`
`ListItems.Select(item =>
                {
                    long value;
                    bool parseSuccess = long.TryParse(item.Key, out value);
                    return new { Key = value, parseSuccess, item.Value };
                })
                .Where(parsed => parsed.parseSuccess)
                .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
                .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.First().Value)`

Comment: This code will add the first "a" as key and the List.  You cannot add the same key "a" to the dictionary ,which is the sole purpose of adding a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Dictionary<int, List<int>>> list = new List<Dictionary<int, List<int>>>(); //List with a dictinary that contains a list 
int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Key that you want to check if it exist in the dictinary
int temp_counter = 0; 

foreach(Dictionary<Int32,List<int>> dict in list)
{
    if(dict.ContainsKey(key))
    temp_counter+=temp_counter;
}

if (temp_counter == 0) // key not present in dictinary then add a to the list a dictinary object that contains your list
{
    Dictionary<int,List<int>> a = new Dictionary<int,List<int>>();
    a.Add(key,new List<int>()); // will contain your list
    list.Add(a);
}
```

Check if this works